# FindControl Returns a Null Reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, findcontrol, fba

I have two textboxes and I use `FindControl()` to access them:

```
<tr>
        <td align="right">
            <asp:Label ID="LastNameLabel" AssociatedControlID="LastName" runat="server" /></td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="LastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="LastNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="LastName" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <asp:Label ID="PrimaryCompanyLabel" AssociatedControlID="PrimaryCompany" runat="server" /></td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="PrimaryCompany" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PrimaryCompanyRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="PrimaryCompany" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
    </tr>
```

The Textbox `LastName` is being accessed fine but the second, `PrimaryCompany` is returning a *null reference*

They are being access by:

```
private IEditableTextControl _txtLastName;
    protected IEditableTextControl txtLastName
    {
        get
        {
            if (_txtLastName == null)
            {
                _txtLastName = (IEditableTextControl)this.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("LastName");
            }
            return _txtLastName;
        }
    }

private IEditableTextControl _txtPrimaryCompany;
    protected IEditableTextControl txtPrimaryCompany
    {
        get
        {
            if (_txtPrimaryCompany == null)
            {
                _txtPrimaryCompany = (IEditableTextControl)this.CompleteStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("PrimaryCompany");
            }

            return _txtPrimaryCompany;
        }
    }
```

This code is from the SharePoint2013 FBAPack in CodePlex. The `LastName` field is built-in while the `PrimaryCompany` field is being added by me.

I'm only showing this part of the code as the `null reference` is being thrown here. Am I missing something?

Comment: You find them in different containers: CreateUserStep and CompleteStep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason `IEditableTextControl` doesn't work on the field that I created. I used `TextBox` instead and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's here that the null reference is being thrown? Do you have a line number? Here the control is actually being checked for null.

My guess is that it's actually elsewhere in the code that it happens, because the .Text property is null.  For example if you do something like:

txtPrimaryCompany.Text.Trim()